# Can't get data from html using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having issues getting data from a website.

So I want android studio to show the html in the logcat.

When I am entering the app,the screen become white and unresponsive.

I am getting no errors.

every time I try using AsyncTask and it just refusing to work.

Thanks for the help.

btw,I allowed the INTERNET permission on "Android Manifest".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    
                String result = "";
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    
                try {
    
                    url = new URL(urls[0]);
    
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    
                    int data = reader.read();
    
                    while (data != -1) {
                        char current = (char) data;
                        result += current;
                        data = reader.read();
                    }
    
                    return result;
    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
            DownloadTask download = new DownloadTask();
            String result = null;
    
            try {
    
                result = download.execute("https://www.usmagazine.com/celebrities/a/").get();
                Log.d("WORKING?", result);
    
            }catch (Exception e){
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Can't get data from html ....` ! From html? How do you mean?

Comment: `...../a/").get();`  Remove the .get() and handle the result of doInBackground() in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
return result;
```

in doInBackground returns result to a method called onPostExecute in your AsyncTask. Please override that method, and perform the task there.